# Using a SMPS converter IC as a controller

Tags: led, mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor

I'm building an LED driver using the [LM3410](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3410.pdf). The internal switch supports a current of about 2A which should be adequate for my needs, but if I need more, can I use an external MOSFET to act as a switch instead? I was thinking a pFET with the gate connected to the switching pin, since in a boost converter the inductor is connected to ground during the charging phase.

Comment: There are lots of SMPS ICs to choose from, many will support an optional external switching transistor.

Comment: That is true and I'm looking elsewhere, but I'm asking more in general. There are some non-controller ICs that have very desirable characteristics that I can't find elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

My impression by reading "Theory of operation" and the schematic in figure 13 of the datasheet is that you will break the control loop:

> IL ismeasured by the current sense amplifier, which generates an output proportional to the
>   switch current.

[image]

Comment: Oh that's strange. My bad. I assumed from the example circuits that the current was measured with a sense resistor.